# Can I prompt user to input some parameters using spark sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark-sql

I know in Oracle you can prompt user to input parameters using the colon, for example, if I want to ask user to change the end date before user runs the query I can do: to_date (:end_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') and it will pop up a window for the user to input a specific end_date when user executes.

I want to do the same using spark sql but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIK spark doesn't support such a feature. But if you want to do this, you can use pyspark to get the input from python and pass it into spark sql.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: What you describe is not a feature of the database, but of the client program you are using to interface with the database.